# Add models to java classpath

Tags: java, classpath, src, opennlp, bin

How can I add below OpenNLP models to my java web application classpath ? I just copied the "en-parser-chunking.bin" file to my java web application src folder. But it gives me the class not found exception. What is the correct way to add this file to my classpath in tomcat 9 ?

[Open NLP Tools Models](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/)

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: yah. i have installed maven plugin in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If using Maven, create a folder structure under `src/main/resources/` that reflects the package of the class you are using to load the model. For example, `src/main/resources/mycompany/myapp/`.

You will be able to load the model using this code:

```
InputStream modelIn = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
model = new ParserModel(modelIn);
            modelIn.close();
```

You can find more information on [Apache OpenNLP Documentation](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/), more specifically in the [Parser API docs](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.parser.parsing.api).

Comment: Hello Sir. Should I do this in build path or in mavan pom.xml. Since I'm new to java and maven. I'm not clear how to do this

Comment: It is in the directory structure of your project.